# Multiple annotations @JsonPath are not working

Tags: apache-camel, jsonpath

I am calling a REST service via http4 Camel's component and I want to map the JSON response to some headers. For that reason I used jsonpath language.

```
<route>
   ...
   <toD uri="http4://theCallingServiceUrl"/>

   <setHeader headerName="CamelAddressesLink">
      <jsonpath>$._links.collection/addresses.href</jsonpath>
   </setHeader>
   <setHeader headerName="CamelAvailabilitiesLink">
     <jsonpath>$._links.collection/availabilities.href</jsonpath>
   </setHeader>
</route>
```

Problem occurs when i try to do the same thing via bean.

```
public void test(@JsonPath("$._links.collection/addresses.href") String address,
                 @JsonPath("$._links.collection/availabilities.href") String availabilities) {
            ...
}
```

I am getting the following

```
Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Expected to find an object with property ['_links'] in path $ but found 'java.lang.String'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.
```

Any ideas? If i try to extract only one value from JSON it works, problem occurs if i try to add more than one @JsonPath annotations.

Thanks!

Comment: Try turn on stream caching, see this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

Comment: I already tried this and still not working.

Comment: Can you maybe build a small sample app and post it on github or attach as ZIP file and create a Camel JIRA ticket, then its easier for us to use that to dive into finding a solution.

Comment: Claus it seems that bean resets the stream cache setting of the route. Is there a reason why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that bean component resets the stream cache. Thus, even though I set the stream cache to the route, this setting is removed when the bean is executed. That is the reason why we can use only 1 @JsonPath.

An alternative to to convert the body to String right after the http4 component with

```
<toD uri="http4://theCallingServiceUrl"/>
<convertBodyTo type="String"/>
```

and now our bean will work with as many @JsonPath as we want.